# Chat Application like Hangout/facebook

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-websocket, livechat

I am now to coding so may be it's a there is obvious answer of this question. can we embed google hangout in out Spring/Hibernate web application for chatting? Or i have to start from beginning to develop a new one. I can make a simple application using spring,hibernate, jQuery,AJAX, Mysql but I want a standard one in which video call is also there and smileys . Please input your suggestions! Cheers !!